# How do I "Mod-Out" Aquifers in an Already Generated World?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

On the Dwarf Fortress Wiki page for Aquifers says to do the following to remove aquifers:

"Find the files in Dwarf Fortress/raw/objects (new world) or Dwarf Fortress/data/save/regionNN/raw/objects (already saved world).
Open the three files with a text editor (e.g. Notepad). (inorganic_stone_layer.txt, inorganic_stone_mineral.txt, and inorganic_stone_soil.txt)
Use Edit->Replace, and replace [AQUIFER] with (AQUIFER). (Use 'Replace All').
To restore the tags later, do the same in reverse. (Replacing (AQUIFER) with [AQUIFER])."

I did all of this for both the new world and already saved world methods, and checked to make sure that [AQUIFER] no longer exists in any of these files, and the aquifer is still there. Does anyone know if this is the right way to remove aquifers by modding?

Comment: This will prevent aquifers from generating in any new worlds, but will not remove them from existing worlds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DFHack** has script called [drainaquifer](https://github.com/peterix/dfhack#drainaquifer). It will find and reset aquifier tiles, they will stop generating water.

You can remove water by using [liquids](https://github.com/peterix/dfhack#liquids) plugin.

Comment: I made script, thar remove only visible aquifier tiles. In case i need aquifier later (infinite water source is good for flooding traps). If you need it, I will share it here.

Comment: I went and downloaded the script for drainaquifer, and I put it in the hack/scripts folder, but the script doesn't work in DFHack. When I type ls to list all plugins and scripts, drainaquifer doesn't show up, and "drainaquifer" isn't recognized when I type it in to DFHack. I followed the instructions on the page. What am I missing?

Comment: you may have old version of dfhack, most recent version is on the [forum](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=91166.0).

Also with dfhack you can pour magma in water near aqufier to make obsidian wall, that will stop water.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Got the newest dfhack and got the script to work! Thanks for all of the help!